# Javascript working in Chrome, working in firefox locally, but not after deployment

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

This is part of a Spark Java app, but the error is happening in this JS part. The relevant code is as follows:

```
const addErrBox = async () => {
    const controls = document.querySelector(".pure-controls");
    const errBox = document.createElement("p");
    errBox.setAttribute("id", "errBox");
    errBox.setAttribute("style", "color:red");
    errBox.innerHTML = "Short URL not valid or already in use!";
    controls.appendChild(errBox);
}

const submitForm = () => {
    const form = document.forms.namedItem("new-url-form");
    const longUrl = form.elements["longUrl"];
    const shortUrl = form.elements["shortUrl"];

    const url = `/api/new`;

    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: `${longUrl.value};${shortUrl.value}`
    })
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                if (document.getElementById("errBox") == null) {
                    addErrBox();
                }
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("errBox")?.remove();
                longUrl.value = "";
                shortUrl.value = "";

                refreshData();
            }
        });

};

(async () => {
    await refreshData();
    const form = document.forms.namedItem("new-url-form");
    form.onsubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
})();
```

Basically, "/api/new" checks for validity of input, adds the data to database if valid and prints error otherwise. Now, when the input is valid, it seems to work. The "/api/new" code is in Java, which seems to work properly as well since I do get a 400 error. All of it works properly when built inside a docker locally, but when accessed over internet using Nginx reverse proxy, it stops working inside firefox. Chrome still works. I'm not sure what's happening.
The code for "/api/new" is this:

```
public static String addUrl(Request req, Response res) {
        var body = req.body();
        if (body.endsWith(";")) {
            body = body + "$";
        }
        var split = body.split(";");

        String longUrl = split[0];
        
        if (split[1].equals("$")) {
            split[1] = Utils.randomString();
        }
        String shortUrl = split[1];
        shortUrl = shortUrl.toLowerCase();
        
        var shortUrlPresent = urlRepository
                .findForShortUrl(shortUrl);

        if (shortUrlPresent.isEmpty() && Utils.validate(shortUrl)) {
            return urlRepository.addUrl(longUrl, shortUrl);
        } else {
            res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST_400);
            return "shortUrl not valid or already in use";
        }
    }
```

**Update:** it suddenly started working, without any change on the server side. I think it was some kind of issue with caching, either in firefox, cloudflare or Nginx's part.